# How to control the the behaviour of wp_insert_post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wp_insert_post to bulk insert posts into Wordpress, according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post it seems like the method does many tag manipulation for the content supplied, for example, it will replace a `<br>` tag if it finds a newline `\n` character in the string. I wonder how could we turn this feature off, as in my case I have all the content pre-processed and I want Wordpress take them as is. The `kses_remove_filters()` and `'post_content_filtered' => true,` lines are my attempts to solve this problem, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
kses_remove_filters();
$my_post = array(
'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($json_str['title'][0]),
'post_content' => $json_str['content'],
'post_date' => $json_str['pdate'],
'post_name' => $json_str['alias'][0],
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_author' => 1,
'post_category' => array(2, $catid),
'post_content_filtered' => true,
);
wp_insert_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> wp_insert_post() passes data through sanitize_post(), which itself handles all necessary sanitization and validation (kses, etc.).

In `wp-includes/post.php` line ~394, comment this line out:

```
$_post = sanitize_post( $post, 'raw' );
```

But it is generally a bad idea to [hack core files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/).

Comment: looks like that previous line checks `if ( empty( $post->filter )`, maybe we can just set that field something instead of hacking the core files?